# Mongo shell giving out the error "Multiple occurrences of option"

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

When using the following command

```
mongo --username admin_user --password passw#ord^s --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I get the error ""Error parsing command line:  Multiple occurrences of option "--username". The version of Mongo shell 3.0.12. Can anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I managed to find the issue. The current user didn't seem to have permission to mongo shell properly for some reason. When I add "sudo" to the beginning it worked fine.