# I can't get into my mongo shell with admin, anyone know why?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

`mongo -u admin -p area51iph!! --authenticationDatabase=admin`

I tried to get into my shell with admin and i just set up the authentication. I can't seem to log into it with the admin account. When I try I get this error:

```
Error parsing command line:  Multiple occurrences of option "--username"
try 'mongo --help' for more information
```

Does anyone know any reasons this could happen/

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874966/mongo-shell-giving-out-the-error-multiple-occurrences-of-option?

Comment: yep i did and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
 mongo --username admin --password area51iph!! --authenticationDatabase admin
```

See [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/)

Comment: ye it says the same thing